# Database of Latin Church Music

Tags: chant

Wondering if there is an online (and free or open source) database/collection of Latin Church music. By that I mean, Gregorian Chant type stuff like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ca4v_y9AfM8), other monophonic chanting (stuff from 1000-1500CE), or even modern liturgical stuff like the latin songs you would hear in a large Church today (I'm not sure what these really sound like or if they are polyphonic or not). But basically some sort of melodies in the Latin churches. It [sounds like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NyV01zXuW-A#t=2m30s) it could be polyphonic as well.

Basically just looking for any available sheet music for stuff like that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because requests for off-site resources are off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of two resources, though neither are exclusively dedicated to Latin church music.

1. IMSLP, a very large online library of public domain scores, has a
   category page for [plainchant](https://imslp.org/wiki/Category:Plainchant).
2. Hymnary.org's [advanced search](https://hymnary.org/search?qu=hymnalLanguages%3Alatin) allows you to choose a language, so you can search for only Latin hymnals.

Comment: Oh this is great: https://imslp.org/wiki/Category:Scores :)

Comment: @LancePollard The [Choral Public Domain Library](https://www.cpdl.org/wiki/) might also be of interest.

Comment: https://gregobase.selapa.net/